# What is the name on the bottle of Scotch in the final episode of Star Trek Enterprise?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise

In the final episode of Star Trek Enterprise, "These are the Voyages", Archer and Trip are drinking a toast from a bottle of Scotch (timestamp 27:23) All I can make out is "20 Year", Malt, "Scotch Whiskey". The name looks like two words or names each beginning with "D". Can anyone make out the name, and is it a real Scotch or something they made up for the show?

Comment: Can you please give a time stamp for this?

Comment: Sorry, what are you referring to?  It was the final episode of Enterprise...

Comment: He means the time in minutes and seconds since the start of the episode that the scene in question occurs.

Comment: Do you have a screengrab?

Comment: Which is interesting as Scotch implies Scottish Whisky but Whiskey (with an E) suggests Irish.

Comment: I always thought it would have been 'classier' for them to use a bottle of our 25-year old Scotch, it then being several hundred years smoother.

Comment: Inaccuracies are easily explained by the fact that *Enterprise* takes place entirely on the holodeck.

Comment: @CGCampbell whisky doesn't continue to "smoothen" in the bottle. The age is the time spent in the barrel.

Answer (score 14):

With contrast enhanced, you can clearly see the label reads "Brannon & Braga".

[image]

This is obviously an in-joke relating to the show's producer, [Brannon Braga](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brannon_Braga)

Comment: Think it's indeed "Berman & Braga". There's not enough space for two "n" IMO.

Answer (score 10):

While I do not feel that this is a certain answer, not having a copy of the episode in question nor even having watched it, some participants on [the talk page of Memory Alpha's article on the episode](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Talk:These_Are_the_Voyages..._%28episode%29#Whiskey_Label_Easter_Egg) believe the label is "Berman & Braga", an in-joke referencing Rick Berman and Brannon Braga, the co-creators of the series.

Comment: Thanks for the link. That is the only reference I've seen for it.  Still, it looks like D**** and D******* to me.  That's looking at it on Netflix. Pretty funny if that's the case.